# Detect unreferenced or changes to constants defined in js on compilation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, web-development-server

Is there a way to detect old references to js constants that have updated or changed but are still being referenced in my project? I am using angularjs, and so far I've had to use a separate program that skims through the definitions I've pointed to,then all the files in my project scripts folder to warn me of conflicts, but I have to run this manually and I bet there is a better way to handle these things. Does anyone know if this can be done on compile before hitting my browser?

Comment: 1. Constants should by definition not update or change. What exactly is your question? A program that detects coding errors? ESLint for example?

Comment: We split our constants out so each set of constants reference a certain web page or section. In the home page it might be homeConstants and we inject that into the home controller, but maybe someone decides to add another constant within that file named homeConstantsBroadcasts and move some from homeCons to HomeBroadcastsConst. It is 100% user error but it would be nice to be able to catch that before it happens. I will look into ESLint, thanks.